# Splunk - elasticsearch integration

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, splunk-query

We have a requirement to display elasticsearch data on splunk GUI
is there a way to query elasticsearch from splunk GUI and get the results on splunk GUI

Comment: depends on the complexity of the query and how splunk handle json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://github.com/brunotm/elasticsplunk
It bundles:
- elasticsearch-py
- urllib3
- splunklib (from the splunk-sdk-python)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped me. the results i am getting from the query are being displayed under statistics. Can you please suggest how to get them under events.

Answer (score 0):

What's the goal ? By doing this, you are doing the job twice as both are Log analysis platform, but Splunk is a paid version. Index in Splunk direclty or separate usages

Comment: The goal is to display  results  on splunk which will help me to configure alerts but i need not do indexing on splunk.